# If a Hilbert space is linearly isometric to a Banach space, will the Banach space be a Hilbert space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, isometry

> Question: Given two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$, if there exists an onto linear isometry $T:X\to Y$ and $X$ is a Hilbert space, is it true that $Y$ is a Hilbert space?

Intuitively this seems true to me.
To prove this, one just need to construct an $\langle\cdot, \cdot \rangle$ on $Y\times Y$ and show that it is an inner product.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity